# How to use OpenVPN but not require it?

Tags: networking, network-manager, openvpn

I built an Ubuntu machine for my in-laws (who live nearly 1000 miles away) and configured NetworkManager via the GUI to act as a VPN client to my network. I had to "push route-gateway" with the IP of their router so that it wouldn't automatically try to set the default route to the VPN.

Whenever the VPN client is unable to connect to my network, they can surf the Web only for about 1-2 minutes before being disconnected.

How can I break the requirement that the VPN should be up so that they can surf even if the VPN connection fails?

Answer (score 1):

In the "Edit Connections" dialog of Network Manager, ensure the third box down is not ticked.

[image]

Comment: I tried that but then it requires them to bring up the VPN manually. I want the system to attempt to connect the VPN automatically but keep the wired connection up **even if** it fails.